# MediaPlayer: How to retrieve metadata with MediaMetadataRetriever?

Tags: java, android

my MediaPlayer is working, but I need to retrieve the metadata e.g. stream title. I'm using this code for it:

```
public String getMeta(){
        meta = new MediaMetadataRetriever();
        meta.setDataSource("http://111.1111.1111.1111:1111");
        return meta.extractMetadata(MediaMetadataRetriever.METADATA_KEY_ALBUM);
```

But I'm only getting a empty String from this. I also tried all constants for the meta. I'm not sure, but I think the problem is around the connection to the webstation. My MediaPlayer has a Listener e.g. mPlayer.setOnPreparedListener(new OnPreparedListener() {...}. But for the MediaMetadataRetriever does not exist one.

Can someone help me? Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

I don't have any idea about media player, but it's possible to use **[Apache Tika](https://tika.apache.org/)** to extract metadata about file:

Here is a my code of extract metadata of a file:

```
InputStream is = new FileInputStream("/home/rahul/Music/03 - I Like Your Music.mp3");

Parser parser = new AutoDetectParser();
BodyContentHandler handler = new BodyContentHandler();

Metadata metadata = new Metadata();
parser.parse(is, handler, metadata, new ParseContext());

String handler = handler.toString();
System.out.println("Handler data: " + handler);
System.out.println(metadata.get(Metadata.CREATION_DATE));
System.out.println(metadata.get(Metadata.LAST_MODIFIED));
```

It will extract the metadata like we can see at:

[image: Apache Tika Metadata]

Comment: This seems a bit too oversized. I only need the stream title. Any ideas how to use the android media metadata retriever?

Comment: `System.out.println(metadata.get(Metadata.TITLE));` you can get title. No idea about android media metadata retriever

Answer (score 1):

Apacke Tika is too large and limited to use in a mobile application. Try [FFmpegMediaMetadataRetriever](https://github.com/wseemann/FFmpegMediaMetadataRetriever) (Disclaimer: it's my project). It has the same interface as MediaMetadataRetriever:

```
FFmpegMediaMetadataRetriever retriever = new FFmpegMediaMetadataRetriever();
retriever.setDataSource("http://someurl");
retriever.release();
```

Comment: is it possible to use at the same time as MediaPlayer???, because I'm getting: IO Error creating local socket at java.io.IOException: Address already in use. Seems like the MediaPlayer is already using the socket...

Answer (score 1):

The reason why you are not getting any results from MediaMetadataRetriever.extractMetaData() is because your examples calls setDataSource(String path) which only will load local files. If you want to pass in a remote URL then you need to call setDataPath(String uri, Map headers) method.